# CodeIgniter losing session information

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a CI app that uses db sessions, and a few hundred users on at any one time.

Sessions work perfectly for everyone, except one guy, who keeps getting booted back to the auth/login controller after a few actions. It seems that clearing his cache works for a few days, but the problem then comes back.

As far as I am aware, he is the only user with this problem. Even his business partner sits next to him on a different pc and does not suffer the same problem.

Apparently he is using IE (8 or 9, cant remember which). I asked him to try chrome or FF, which he has said gives the same problem. I’m not sure if he actually has tried them or not…but I can’t exactly argue with the guy.

Needless to say, the guy is pretty pissed off and ready to throw his pc out the window…or perhaps at me.

Any ideas on what to do or suggest here?

Comment: Need more information.  What is he doing?  Does his access level to you program have him touch code that other uses don't see? etc. etc.

Comment: Is it AJAX-heavy, or do you serve any resources (i.e. images) through CI requests that autoload the session library?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary here. He has exact same access level as everyone else, not doing anything special or different to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it seems that this was caused by the user being on a USB mobile dongle. Same laptop on a wireless network worked fine. Go figure.